# Issue in Visual Studio when doing activity in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, webforms

When I select any option from Dropdown list debugger getting hit each time

[image]

This is the place where debugger getting stop, but there is no breakpoint added

[image]

This issue is happening each time I select any item from dropdown.

Comment: Also, why are you using WebForms in 2023?

Comment: Your breakpoint is being hit every time you perform something (like clicking on a drop-down item) because that will trigger a `__doPostBack()` call, which will `POST` the entire `<form>` and cause the entire page (`.aspx`) to be re-rendered and sent to the browser. If you are using _ASP.NET AJAX_ with `UpdatePanel` then that will still re-render the page server-side, but ASP.NET will "crop" the response to just the text-range of the `<asp:UpdatePanel>` WebControl. HTH.

Comment: Thank for the explanation @Dai

Is there a way to Avoid this, as I mentioned earlier that there is no breakpoint placed still debugger getting hit.

Comment: I just noticed that your screenshot is actually showing the **JavaScript** debugger, attached to Chrome. I suggest you disable Chrome JS debugging in VS and stick to Chrome's own built-in debugger instead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: disabling  Chrome JS debugging in VS worked, Thank a lot @Dai

Comment: @SatyamShaw If Dai's answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 2):

(Posting my comment as an answer as the OP confirmed it fixed it for them:)

I just noticed that your screenshot is actually showing the JavaScript debugger, attached to Chrome. See the circled bit here:

[image]

I suggest you disable Chrome JS debugging in VS and stick to Chrome's own built-in debugger instead:

[image]